# how to get selected cell value in Iframe in mxGraph?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, mxgraph, jgraph

How can we get selected cell value in frame? I called iframe by clicking link. and in Iframe I want to get Attribute values of selected cell.

```
 <script>
        function main(container) {
            if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported()) {
                mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
            }
            else {
                var graph = new mxGraph(container);
                var cell = graph.getSelectionCell();
            }
  </script>

<body onload="main(window.parent.document.getElementById('graphContainer'))">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Is the iFrame on the same domain ? can you show us your HTML setup .. perhaps a http://jsfiddle.net example ?

Comment: yes, Iframe is in same domain.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using something like a button

you can get most of the info you are looking from the  evt

for example:

```
    graph.addListener(mxEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, function(sender, evt)
    {
        var cell = evt.getProperty('cell');
        if (cell != null && cell.parent != main_class) {
                main_class = cell.edges[0].value.slice(14, cell.edges[0].value.indexOf('-') );
```

etc....

you can obviously use the debugger in firefox to figure where the property you are looking for resides in the  taxonomy